# Load() doesn't seems to run when I set initial files

Tags: filepond

I am struggling to set up initial files.  I have tried both `pond.addFile()` and `files: {}` in filePond options, but both of them return 400 Can't load URL.

I have checked my console, but I cannot find the related XHR request or the corresponding `console.log()` I wrote in my custom `load()` function. My guess is load() never fired.  What could go wrong here?

My load function:

```
load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
            var myRequest = new Request(source);
            console.log('Load function running');
            console.log(source);
            fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
              response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
                load(myBlob)
              });
            });
        }
```

Comment: When you run `addFile`, the `load` method is not used, it's only used for existing files in the `files` array, and then only for files marked as `local`. FilePond will load urls using an internal method. It's possible that the URL is remote and CORS hasn't been configured properly?

See: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-object/#setting-initial-files

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Rik.  If I understand you and the doc correctly, I have to run `addFile` to render files I marked in `files` array in `FilePond.create()`, and they have to be local.

As `addFile` is only for loading image from `files`,  if I need to preload an image from external url, which method should I use then?